# How to add explicit width and heights on image that changes sizes due to device, to disable layout shift in pages?

Tags: css, image, image-size

I am facing CLS problems and https://pagespeed.web.dev/ recommend me to set explicit width and heights on images, but i just don't understand how i suppose to do this. For example:
If i set width and height for mobile, problem will be actual for desktops and tablets.
I am using media queries for changing image sizes for different devices, but to fix CLS problems i need to add explicit width and heights on image to reduce any shifts on page

I am using dust templates

Any help will be appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This Pagespeed Insights message is misleading, you are NOT required to set the width + height of your images using the HTML attributes, you can also use CSS.

```
Set a width + height in CSS: .your-image { width: 200px; height: 150px; }
```